# Having problems with the actual proof step of epsilon-N sequence convergence proofs

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm having problems actually completing epsilon-N proofs for the convergence of sequences, namely the part where, once I've found an N, I have to work backward to derive the original statement. I almost always up ending in a situation where I simply can't reverse one of the steps, logically speaking.

For instance, what I assume is a very easy example, that $\dfrac{2n-1}{4n^2}$ converges to $0$ and thus $\left|\dfrac{2n-1}{4n^2}\right| < \varepsilon $ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

Finding an $N$ is easy enough:

$\left|\dfrac{2n-1}{4n^2}\right| < \varepsilon $ -- Assuming $n>0$ we can drop the absolute value:

$\dfrac{2n-1}{4n^2} < \varepsilon $ -- Assuming $n>1$ we can create a smaller fraction. This was a method gone over in class:

$\dfrac{1}{4n^2} < \dfrac{2n-1}{4n^2} < \varepsilon $ -- inverting and simplifying:

$n > \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$

So then I choose $N = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$ and reverse the steps, which is all doable and straightforward up to $\dfrac{1}{4n^2} < \varepsilon $.

But at this point I'm stuck, because creating a smaller fraction only works one way; even if $\dfrac{1}{4n^2} < \varepsilon $, that doesn't mean I can make the left side larger and have it still be true. I don't see any other way to get back to the original statement, though. It's possible/likely I made a mistake deriving some part of this, but it happens with virtually every question I try where I have to use the "create a smaller quantity" method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n = \frac {2n-1}{4n^2}$

If $n>1$ then $0<a_n< \frac {1}{2n}$

For any epsilon, if $N > \frac {1}{2\epsilon}$ then $n>N \implies |a_n| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

The following step is taken in the wrong direction. $$\dfrac{1}{4n^2} < \dfrac{2n-1}{4n^2} < \varepsilon$$

You need a larger fraction to be less than $\epsilon$,  not a smaller one.

For example you can work with, $$ \dfrac{2n-1}{4n^2} < \dfrac{2n}{4n^2} <\varepsilon$$
And find n such that $$\dfrac{2n}{4n^2} <\varepsilon$$

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for my confusion, but I'm not following how this isn't just the same problem just in a different step -- why can we make the fraction larger and still have the inequality hold here?

Comment: If I want to prove $a < b $, I can show that  $a<c$ and $c < b $ and use transitive property of $ < $. Note that we proved something larger that $a$ is less than $b$ so $a<b$ follows.